# How to handle window size for GraphicsProgram (ACM library)?

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I want to define the size of the window, but I did not find a clean way to do it. SetSize() gives a strange result:

```
public class Test extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run() {

        setSize(400, 600);
        add(new GLabel("Width: " + getWidth(), 30, 30));
        add(new GLabel("Height: " + getHeight(), 30, 50));
    }

}
```

The result is 384 x 542. The gap is always the same (-16 x -58), so it's easy to build a work around. Is there a way to define the size in useful pixels directly?

Comment: I'd definitely be interested in a way to set the canvas size as well since I had this very same issue earlier tonight, there were workarounds but they were clunky modifications to startercode that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Canvas size is Application Size + px for menu window height/width. It looks like for me its (x,y)(18px,70px ) for menu and bar modifications. Using setSize(x+mod,y+mod) you can get your coordinate system fixed.

Comment: Agreed that I would rather be able to set the canvas size to the usable size directly. There should be some good reasons to have it like that, like integration in a web page.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this while studying the code of a Stanford course project (breakout). GraphicsProgram is not constructed according to its fields, `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT`, `EAST`, `CENTER` etc, automatically. Therefore we need a `resize()` to set the window size which [acm.program.GraphicsProgram](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html) inherits from [java.applet.Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html).
Simply adding a `resize()` and `pause()` will do the work.

```
public class Test extends GraphicsProgram {
    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int PAUSE = 10; // or whatever interval you like

    public void run() {
        this.resize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        pause(PAUSE);
        // game logic here
        ...
    }

}
```

The `pause()` is necessary as the resize takes time. It avoids the mis-displacement of components if you are adding them right after resizing.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void init() {

    setSize(400, 600);


}
```

instead of setting the size in the run method do it on the init!

Answer (score 1):

After class:
`public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 900;  // x size of window`

Before run:
`public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 540; // y size of window`

Answer (score 0):

No need for setSize or resize.

You just need to add this two public variables:

```
/** Width and height of application window in pixels */
public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 400;
public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 600;
```

and these two if you need exactly WIDTH and HEIGHT to use:

```
/** Dimensions of window (usually the same) */
private static final int WIDTH = APPLICATION_WIDTH;
private static final int HEIGHT = APPLICATION_HEIGHT;
```